# I need help adding a per-user cooldown to my Beg command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making an economy bot, and I want my beg command to have a 60 second cooldown **per user**. If someone can help me add that, that would be great! I also would like to have the ability to, when the user is on cooldown, if they try to use the beg command have it send them a message saying how long they have left to wait until they can beg again. And also for it to save the cooldown in a database, so if the bot goes offline it remembers the cooldown. Thx in advance!

Here's my code for the beg command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith('orb'))return;  

  let user = message.author;

  let amount = 5;

  let beg = await db.fetch(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`);

  let begEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#808080")
  .setDescription(`<:Check:618736570337591296> You've begged and received ${amount} coins`);
  message.channel.send(begEmbed)
  db.add(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, amount)
  db.set(`beg_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`, Date.now())
  }
};

module.exports.help = {
  name:"beg",
  aliases: [""]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well my cooldowns are only for when the bot is online, and Idk how that database works, but here is what you can do in json.
**JSON FILE**

```js
{
"Placeholder": "Placeholder"
}
```

and then on the command, do `variable['U'+message.author.id] = Date.now()`
And if they try to do it again, check if `variable['U'+message.author.id]` exists and then if it does, just do `variable['U'+message.author.id] - Date.now()` which should return milliseconds if I remember correctly, and you should be able to convert to seconds with `(variable['U'+message.author.id] - Date.now())*1000` if I'm not wrong. To delete `variable['U'+message.author.id]`, just do that! `delete variable['U'+message.author.id]`

Comment: This does not have per-command cooldown capabilities. Also, I'm generally against spoonfeeding solutions with no explanation as to how it works, especially when there are already plenty of guides (including official ones) documenting how to create one's own command cooldown mechanism.

Comment: I'm sorry, but cooldowns are difficult do to when you want to keep it when the bot is restarting, as usually you would use setTimeout()